Why connectionState property of RTCPeerConnection object is not accesssible?
According to the MDN manual, RTCPeerConnection has a property connectionState (Indicates the current state
of the peer connection by returning one of the strings).
But my program (javascript) does not see it.
Developer tools (console in Firefox) do not show this property too - see curPeerConnection variable in the screenshot.
Why I do not see it ?

In what browser and version? In a new JS console without any polyfills, does 'connectionState' in RTCPeerConnection.prototype return true?

Philipp Hancke, it is Firefox, v.112.1. As regards prototype - I'll watch that a little later.

There you have your answer, Firefox was a bit late in shipping that.

As MDN says connectionState only shipped in Firefox 113. You may want to use the adapter.js polyfill which approximates connectionState based on the iceConnectionState which is somewhat correct and lets you write code that uses connectionState and the connectionStateChange event.
Note that 112 is quite old, even Firefox ESR is at 115 now so you may want to think about what to do with users on old versions

Philipp Hancke, thank you very much! I really didn't notice that not all versions FF support this property!
